# How to change image hue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an image hue changer using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. The problem is that I need to change the image hue using javascript. I've tried using `document.getElementById("output").style` but nothing about hue showed up. I am able to change hue using HTML and CSS:

HTML: `<img id="output" width="0" height="0" style="border: 0px solid black" class="huerotate">`

CSS: `.huerotate {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);}`.

I haven't been able to replicate that using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is called `filter` (ignoring `webkit`), not anything to do with `hue`.

```
document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "hue-rotate(180deg)";
```

Or with `webkitFilter`:

```
document.getElementById("output").style.webkitFilter = "hue-rotate(180deg)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:
(element).style.filter = "hue-rotate(180deg)";

That is at least how I think you want it.
Hope it helps! GL

Edit: I forgot to add the Style property to the element.